# Replace this cursor function to a while loop function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I made this stored procedure that takes as parameters `username, password, firstname, lastname, DOB, email` from a table I created called `newusers` and puts them in the corresponding tables which have the fields mentioned. I used this cursor function to do it but they told me that a cursor isn't a good idea so how can I replace this with a while loop function?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Savenewuser] 
AS 
    DECLARE @username VARCHAR(100); 
    DECLARE @password VARCHAR(100); 
    DECLARE @firstname VARCHAR(100); 
    DECLARE @lastname VARCHAR(100); 
    DECLARE @address VARCHAR(100); 
    DECLARE @birthdate DATE; 
    DECLARE @email VARCHAR(100); 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE newuser_cursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT username, 
               password, 
               firstname, 
               lastname, 
               address, 
               birthdate, 
               email 
        FROM   newuser 

    OPEN newuser_cursor 

    FETCH next FROM newuser_cursor INTO @username, @password, @firstname, 
        @lastname, @address, @birthdate, @email 
END 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO users (username, password) 
        SELECT @username, @password 

    FETCH next FROM newuser_cursor INTO @username, @password, @firstname, 
          @lastname, @address, @birthdate, @email 
END 

CLOSE newuser_cursor 

BEGIN 
    OPEN newuser_cursor 

    FETCH next FROM newuser_cursor INTO @username, @password, @firstname, 
        @lastname, @address, @birthdate, @email 
END 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO userdetails (first_name, last_name, user_address, dob) 
          SELECT @firstname, @lastname, @address, @birthdate 

    FETCH next FROM newuser_cursor INTO @username, @password, @firstname, 
        @lastname, @address, @birthdate, @email 
END 

CLOSE newuser_cursor 

BEGIN 
    OPEN newuser_cursor 

    FETCH next FROM newuser_cursor INTO @username, @password, @firstname, 
        @lastname, @address, @birthdate, @email 
END 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO emailbook (email) 
         SELECT @email 

    FETCH next FROM newuser_cursor INTO @username, @password, @firstname, 
         @lastname, @address, @birthdate, @email 
END 

CLOSE newuser_cursor 

DEALLOCATE newuser_cursor
```

Comment: You already using a `WHILE` loop -which is bad-. Why you want to use a `WHILE` loop?

Comment: i dont know my boss told me to use while loop instead of cursor because its better and faster than cursor @Sami

Comment: Your stored proc makes no sense. You pass in parameters then just overwrite them. You have BEGIN/END in illogical places. You open and close cursors needlessly.

Comment: @nick.mcdermaid the proc has no input parameters (they would be placed between proc name and the AS keyword), it has a bunch of temp variables though (lines prefixed by DECLARE). It does also make sense, in that the newuser table is queried RBAR pulling one line at a time into the temp vars then inserting the data into the destination table.. it's just hugely inefficient and unnecessary

Comment: Haha I completely missed that bit... I just assumed those were parameters when I scanned the code. (because that would actually make sense!) So this proc has a serious concurrency issue in that if the source table is altered midway through there will be unexpected results.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is just for this question, I do not recommend to use this approach in any case.

Since you want to do this by using cursor only, so refining your query.

You don't need to open and close your cursor after every `insert` command, since you'll get the records in first `fetch` statement then afterward you may write all of your `insert` command in one go. then `close` and `deallocate` cursor.

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Savenewuser] 
    AS 
    DECLARE @username VARCHAR(100); 
    DECLARE @password VARCHAR(100); 
    DECLARE @firstname VARCHAR(100); 
    DECLARE @lastname VARCHAR(100); 
    DECLARE @address VARCHAR(100); 
    DECLARE @birthdate DATE; 
    DECLARE @email VARCHAR(100); 
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE newuser_cursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT username, 
            password, 
            firstname, 
            lastname, 
            address, 
            birthdate, 
            email 
        FROM   newuser 

        OPEN newuser_cursor 

        FETCH next FROM newuser_cursor INTO @username, @password, @firstname, 
        @lastname, @address, @birthdate, @email 


        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
        BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO users (username, password) 
            SELECT @username, @password 

            INSERT INTO userdetails (first_name, last_name, user_address, dob) 
            SELECT @firstname, @lastname, @address, @birthdate 

            INSERT INTO emailbook (email) 
            SELECT @email 

            FETCH next FROM newuser_cursor INTO @username, @password, @firstname, 
            @lastname, @address, @birthdate, @email 
        END 

        CLOSE newuser_cursor 

        DEALLOCATE newuser_cursor 
    END
```

Comment: thank you for that i will modify the syntax as you suggested @darkrob

Comment: Yes it answers the question as required. But we all agree this is the wrong way to do it.

Comment: why downvoted, i already mention on the top that this just for the ans purpose and not recommended to use this approach. and if you can read the comments it is the requirement of this question, otherwise simple INSERT...SELECT query is sufficient for this.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need cursors at all. This entire thing can (and should - sql server ALWAYS discourages operations on sets of data that are done in a row-by-row basis) be done as INSERT ... SELECT

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Savenewuser] 
AS 

BEGIN 


      INSERT INTO users 
                  (username, 
                   password) 
      SELECT username, 
             password 
      FROM newuser;

      INSERT INTO userdetails 
                  (first_name, 
                   last_name, 
                   user_address, 
                   dob) 
      SELECT firstname, 
             lastname, 
             address, 
             birthdate 
      FROM newuser;
```

And so on

Not really sure what you're doing about primary keys though..

As noted before, always try to work with a million records as a single block of a million records, not a cursor that pulls a single record at a time, one million times

Comment: yeah i know its easier to do it that way but i was told to do it using the while loop function specifically @caiusjard

Comment: You have a pointy haired boss. `While` is basically the same as a `cursor`. Anyone with any clue would know that you need to use INSERT/SELECT. Note though that your original stored proc makes no sense anyway, so neither does this implementation of it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointy-haired_Boss

Comment: In a transaction would be even better(though it's hard to imagine what would go wrong as you don't seem to have primary keys to violate, but maybe a length limit somewhere would be breached).. but I really do think you should consider adding a guid userid column to new user and to all your tables, and inserting that too, because all this code does right now is break up related data in a way that means it's fairly impossible to reliably put back together.. and that's a grave mistake

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yeah i know it can simply be done by INSERT/SELECT i dont know what she is thinking off , concerning my stored proc it actually worked fine it got all the fields from the table newusers and distributed them to the other tables accordingly

Comment: @CaiusJard yeah i know i already have a primary key in all the tables , i just forgot to add it in the stored procedure , i modified it and fixed the problem

Comment: Your proc uses table `newuser`. What happens when two people call this proc at the same time? I assume they are both truncating/inserting into that table at the same time. This proc has a concurrency issue. The trivial fix is to actually use the parameters that are being passed in.

Comment: @nick.mcdermaid this whole thing has more far reaching issues than worrying about concurrency, but I'm not really sure what you mean by "parameters that are passed in"- the OP's sproc also uses table `newuser` and doesn't have any input parameters as far as I can see? Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: You're right there are no parameters. Only a table with a concurrency issue. This fails if it two users modify that table and run it at the same time. That's an actual bug as opposed to the other issue which is just way too much unnecessary complicated code.

Comment: Are you implying I need to do something about it? Where does the responsibility stop? I'm here to advise on what I'm presented with; perhaps this procedure is locked elsewhere such that it will never be run concurrently. Ultimately, on SO we have to decide where is a reasonable point to stop fixing, otherwise every question asking about Hello World would be developing the entire application for them. The OP used newuser RBAR, I used newuser as a set operation, and that's my limit of where to stop fixing the problem. You're welcome to edit my answer to add some advice on concurrency if you like

Comment: My apologies if my comments were taken the wrong way. My comment wasn't about your answer (which is correct) it was about the underlying issue with the original stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see in your code you are splitting columns data and inserting into respective tables. I think in this case you achieve this using join only.

---

```
 Insert into #users(username,password)
 Select username,password from #newuser

 Insert into #userdetails(username,firstname, lastname, address, birthdate)
 Select u.username, n.firstname, n.lastname, n.address, n.birthdate 
 from #newuser n join #users u on n.username=u.username

 Insert into #emailbook(username,email)
 Select u.username,n.email 
 from #newuser n join #users u on n.username=u.username
```